# One RibbonX for multiple Excel 2007 workbooks

Tags: excel, ribbonx, vba

I have an Excel 2003 VBA solution I'm converting to Excel 2007.  The solution had a large collection of menus that were used between multiple workbooks.  I've created RibbonX to replicate this functionality, but now I'm to the point where I want to make my Ribbon show up on all these workbooks.  How do I go about this?  When I switch from one workbook to another the Ribbon disappears.  This isn't a VSTO solution just to be clear it is straight Excel with VBA.  I'm hopeful you don't have to put the RibbonX into each workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save it as an add-in (.xlam), which can then be added by other users. This will keep it visible for all workbooks.

Comment: thanks I will try that when I get home tonight.  From VBA is there anything special about disabling and enabling the ribbon whenit is an addin?

Comment: I should say controls on the ribbon. To be more specific.